# Hang after update the software center in ubuntu 14.05

Tags: 14.04, updates, software-center, google-chrome, update-manager

I experienced hang on my laptop after I run the update software center this morning. I haven't planned to update for so long because I don't see the urgency to run software updates  in the past.

But I did it this morning, I am expecting the performance will be increasing after running the software update. But the fact, I encounter computer hang event only open google-chrome with 2 tabs and sublime-text.

I am not sure, how do I search the main problem on this update.. Have anyone experienced the same thing? If os, what's the solution?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of months ago, I tried installing Ubuntu 14.04 on my desktop machine. It ran really well until I installed a ton of recommended updates. Then, boot time was longer, and the system would hang all the time. The software center was almost unusable as well. 

As for a solution, I would recommend using Linux Mint (which I installed instead of Ubuntu); its basically Ubuntu with a different desktop; I find it to work better. Or, you could try Ubuntu 12; I haven't tried it myself, but I have heard that its really good.

If you are determined to keep what you have now, try looking at the update history, and uninstalling whatever the update installed. This is not the best solution, so be very careful so you don't break your system.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately I could not reinstall my system because there are bunch of configuration that I have made, for instance ssh for git and svn, passwordless, etc.

I have did deep investigation for the problem and realize that the main problem is the google chrome.  If I open google chrome, everything will be unresponsive even though I did not open  any site in chrome. It is strange!

For now, I just import all bookmarks from chrome to Firefox and only use Firefox for my daily searching. This might only a temporary solution for me. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help. As far as chrome goes, try uninstalling it and installing chromium. Chromium is just an open source version of chrome. I used it once, and its pretty good. Just install it from the software center. Its still based on chrome, so you might still experience the same problems, but if you love chrome, try giving it a shot.